# What is a JSON Data Source?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, query-string, nancy

I am working on a C# console application using the Nancy Framework and the Spark view engine, and I am trying to replicate something from another project. However, I am very inexperienced with both Javascript and JSON. To call a chat function in my C# code from my HTML, right now I simply use something like the following...

HTML:

```
http://localhost:1234/sendchat?message="this is a test message"
```

C# Code:

```
    Get["/sendchat"] = x =>
    {
        string message = Request.Query.message;
        string message2 = message.Replace("\"", "");
        Console.WriteLine(message2);

        return View["console.spark"];
    };
```

The problem is that this causes the page to reload. In the project I am looking at for reference, they use Javascript/JSON to call the same type of function without doing a page reload. I understand all of it except for the JSON line as I don't understand what the DataSource is...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#typechat").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            event.preventDefault();
            message = escape($("#typechat").attr('value'));
            $.getJSON(dataSource + "?req=sendchat&message=" + message);
            $("#typechat").attr('value', "");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: dataSource is just a variable a string by the looks of it, it is probably defined somewhere else search for "var dataSource"

Comment: Woah, trying to use recent web framework for REST application without exprience with javascript and JSON. Have fun, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataSource` is just an http domain like `http://yourserver.com/possibly/with/a/path`. It'll be a string defined somewhere in the code.

JSON resources are fetched just like regular HTML pages, with a normal GET request over HTTP. The only difference is the content is JSON not HTML. Try this in your browser for example to see the JSON returned by the SO api:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/183579

(If you don't have a browser plugin to format/highlight JSON nicely it might just look like a long messy string)

Answer (score 0):

Data source is propobly some web page

```
dataSource = "http://somepage.com/someaction";
```

wich renders response as json text, response is grabbed and then parsed to javascript object

Comment: Thank you. I realized what a dumb question this was as soon as I posted it -_-